# Rails: filter index via dropdown and checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, filter, parameters

I'm trying to filter an index page of products via a dropdown menu (locations) and a set of checkboxes (categories) and not being very successful with it. I can filter via a dropdown for either location or category. I can also combine the two dropdowns within the one form but if I can't get a working solution to two separate forms.

What i'd like to achieve is a dropdown for location that submits onchange and the categories I'd like to have as checkboxes with a filter button.

The code I have at the moment provides the dropdown and checkboxes but there are some problems:

- the checkboxes list all the categories but when I filter based on these the params are passed as an array but no products are returned in the view
- whenever I filter by category i lose the previous location selection

Here's the relevant code:

Product Model

```
....
has_many :categorizations
has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
has_many :localizations
has_many :locations, :through => :localizations
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
default_scope :order => 'end_date'
scope :not_expired, where('end_date > ?', Time.now)
scope :location, lambda { |*location_id| {:include => :locations, :conditions => ["locations.id = ?", location_id]} }
scope :category, lambda { |*category_id| {:include => :categories, :conditions => ["categories.id = ?", category_id]} }
scope :unique, :group => "title"
```

Controller

```
class LibraryController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:location_id] && params[:category_ids]
    @products = Product.not_expired.unique.location(params[:location_id]).category(params[:category_ids]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
    elsif params[:category_ids]
    @products = Product.not_expired.unique.category(params[:category_ids]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
    elsif params[:location_id]
    @products = Product.not_expired.unique.location(params[:location_id]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
    else
    @products = Product.not_expired.unique.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
    end
  end
end
```

Library index.html.erb

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

      <div class="filter_options">

        <form class="filter_locations", method="get">
          <% @options = Location.all.map { |a| [ a.name, a.id ] } %>
          <%= select_tag "location_id", options_for_select(@options), :onchange => "this.form.submit();", :include_blank => true %> 
        </form>

        <form class="filter_categories", method="get">
          <% for category in Category.all %>
            <%= check_box_tag("[category_ids][]", category.id) %>
            <%= category.name %>
          <% end %>
          <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

I've been going around in circles with this so any direction is greatly appreciated.

to part answer my own question I've modified the library index and used a hidden field in the category form that calls for the location_id param, if it exists, which means I can retain any location selection that's been made after selecting category checkboxes.

Further update is I've added a check for whether the category checkbox is checked by querying the params, updated library index.html.erb below.

Last edit with @rdvdijk input incorporated (Thanks)

library index.html.erb

```
.......
    <%= form_tag( '', :method => :get ) do %>
      <% @options = Location.all.map { |a| [ a.name, a.id ] } %>
      <%= select_tag "location_id", options_for_select((@options), params[:location_id]), :onchange => "this.form.submit();", :include_blank => true %> 
    <% end %>
    <%= form_tag( '', :method => :get ) do %>
      <% if(params.has_key?(:location_id)) %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'location_id', params[:location_id] %> 
      <% end %>
    <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'category_ids[]', category.id, params[:category_ids].to_s.include?(category.id_to_s) %>
      <%= category.name %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
    <% end %>
.......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two forms, I think that is part of your problem. Whenever you change a location in the first form, only the `location_id` will be sent to your controller `index` action. Whenever your select a category and submit the second form, only the `category_ids` will be sent to your controller `index` action.

Use *one form* and see what happens. It should at least make the filtering work for a single submit.

The second problem I see is that you don't select the chosen location, or check the chosen categories.

Take a look at the documentation for [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) and [`check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag) to fix that.

Comment: I can make the selection work when both selections are in one form but that didn't allow me to make independent selections (location or category). I'm now using a hidden field in the category selection that calls for the location param if it exists which allows me now to set location first and then filter categories after. I edited my question to show that modification. I'm not sure I follow the second problem that you raise but I'll check out that documentation. Thanks

Comment: So your problem boils down to: You have two filters. Both filters should be applied when you change the first, and only second of the filters is applied when the change that one. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Following your suggestion I realised that I wasn't selecting the state of either form after I'd made the selection so I added some queries that set the state of the filters based on the params. I made some updates to the original question.   So the filters are working as they should: using either selection on its own submits just that filter unless category is selected after location which submits both and the states are retained.    So my last problem is that while the category_ids are passed as an array the database query isn't returning any products. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I feel that there is a bit too much logic in your form template. You don't need all the `if`, `elsif` and `else` logic for your `checked` variable. Just place the `params[:category_ids].include?(category.id.to_s)` in the `check_box_tag` directly. This would remove 8 lines of your code. Less is more. Also, don't do `for category in Category.all` but do `Category.all.each { |category| .. }`, it's "better" Ruby idiom.

Comment: Also, this question and the comments are getting a bit out of hand. Questions on StackOverflow should be of limited scope. This question deals with a few different topics, you might want to focus on small, more specific questions. See this section of the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Good point, I'll narrow down the questions in the future and mark this as answered. Just one thing about removing the if,elsif and else. I had tried that and got an error for evaluating a nil value when there is no params which is why I used if, elsif.

Comment: @shane Feel free to ask another question that links to this for context, but be sure to clearly demonstrate that you are indeed asking a whole new question. We keep the scope narrow here on a per question basis so that people looking to solve a very specific problem find the best answer quickly, with additional insight below it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, product belongs_to :category and category has_many :products, I modified categories.id to category_id, it works!

```
scope :category, lambda { |*category_id| {:include => :categories, :conditions => ["category_id = ?", category_id]} }
```